# Date field returned as null on GraphQL query despite data existing

Tags: node.js, graphql, typeorm

I'm experiencing an issue with transferring some data from one a PostgreSQL database to a service.

The way the set up is like this:

Service1 sends a GraphQL request to Service2 asking for data. Service2 has this data stored on a PostgreSQL database from which it fetches the information.

The data is modeled as an entity with decorators from TypeORM and GraphQL. The exact field I'm having an issue with is this:

```
   @Column({
        nullable: true,
        type: 'timestamp'
    })
    @Field(() => GraphQLISODateTime, {nullable: true})
    executed_on: Date
```

When the data arrives from the DB to service2, it exists, all the fields are there and the date field exists with its values.

Field when fetched from DB:

```
"executed_on": "2019-10-27T23:00:00.000Z"
```

The field when fetched from Service1:

```
"executed_on": null
```

When it is sent over to service1, I can console.log the data and I see the fields there. I assume since GraphQL sends data as JSON format, the date field becomes a string. Now when this data is being transferred from service1 to elsewhere, all `executed_on` field values become null. I don't know for what reason this occurs. Could it be that since it's a string in now, it doesn't get parsed into the Date field?

A workaround I found was to cycle through each object in the array and simply create a new Date object from the present string value, but this is not something I wish to do because this process takes place in the other service also when I am fetching the data from an external REST API, so it would be bad design I guess? I'm pretty new to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar issue I believe it's due to serialization bug in the GraphQl node module for DateTime types.

This is what's failing:

```
// node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:
completeLeafValue(returnType, result) {
  // this returns null even though a correct "value" is being passed in
  var serializedResult = returnType.serialize(result);
  ...
```

Because it's serializer fails due to "value instanceof Date" and simply returns null:

```
serialize(value) {
  return value instanceof Date ? value.toISOString() : null;
}
```

For some reason type=Date gets cast as "DateTime" Why I haven't figured out yet but in my opinion it should throw an error rather then return just null.

As you've already stated: The only workaround/fix is to create a new Date(...) object for every Date field in your object tree.

Or fork off the original repository and add this code to the "completeLeafValue" method:

```
//node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:
completeLeafValue(returnType, result) {
  var serializedResult = returnType.serialize(result);
  if(completeLeafValue==="DateTime") {
    result = new Date(result);
    //new Date(...) does not throw and only returns null when it fails
    //so we have to check for null
    if(result === null) { 
      throw new Error(`Cannot cast ${result} to Date object`);
    }
  }
  ...(rest or original fn)
```